# Custom Validator Attributes - using other proprty values in error message

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a custom attribute, that relies on other model properties to function.
the attribute takes property name arguments to use to get values out of the associated model to perform validation.
I attach it to a field like this

```
AViewModel{
    [DateBetweenAges(minProperty:"MinAge", maxProperty:"MaxAge", ErrorMessage = "Your age is not between {1} and {2}")]
    public DateTime? DoB { get; set; }

        public int MinAge { get; set; }
        public int MaxAge { get; set; }
}
```

I have hooked this up using a Adapter, and an AdaptorProvider to offer client validation by following the example here [Defining Custom Client Validation Rules in Asp.net Core MVC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/01/03/asp-net-core-mvc/)
but I am having trouble getting the error message to say the correct thing which would be for example: `'Your age is not between 20 and 30'`

20 and 30 being the values attached to the `MinAge` and `MaxAge` properties on the ViewModel (set when the page is loaded)

in the GetErrorMessage(ModelValidationContextBase validationContext) method in the Adapter, I seem to have no way of getting to the values in the ViewModel at all..

in the `IsValid` method of the attribute itself I get these values using reflection by doing

```
var maxprop = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(MaxProperty);
var maxPropVal = maxProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
```

but these seems to be no object instance in the adapter, although inspecting does get me to the ViewData which does have it in..

```
public class DateBetweenAgesAttributeAdapter : AttributeAdapterBase<DateBetweenAgesAttribute>
{
    private readonly DateBetweenAgesAttribute _attribute;

    public DateBetweenAgesAttributeAdapter(DateBetweenAgesAttribute attribute, IStringLocalizer localizer) : base(attribute, localizer)
    {
        _attribute = attribute;
    }

    public override void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-datebetweenages", GetErrorMessage(context));
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-datebetweenages-min", _attribute.MinProperty);
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-datebetweenages-max", _attribute.MaxProperty);
    }

    public override string GetErrorMessage(ModelValidationContextBase validationContext)
    {
return GetErrorMessage(validationContext.ModelMetadata,
            validationContext.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName(),
            //would like to pass the actual minvalue in here,
            //would like to pass the actual maxvalue in here);
    }
..
```

how do I go about that ??

I realise I could use the [Remote] attribute for this, which maybe I will end up doing, but that seems to mean duplicating stuff..

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by putting the attribute's properties into the error message on the Attribute class instead of the Adapter, for example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class DateBetweenAgesAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
    public int MinProperty { get; set; }
    public int MaxProperty { get; set; }

    public DateBetweenAgesAttribute(int min, int max) : base() {
        MinProperty = min;
        MaxProperty = max;
        ErrorMessage = $"Your age is not between {MinProperty} and {MaxProperty}";
    }
}
```

then you don't need to do anything in DateBetweenAgesAttributeAdapter.GetErrorMessage, it just works as is.